# Why Array.new(10) { |e| e = e + 2 } produce [0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18]?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I dont understand the result the block produce in the following examples :

The following array initialization :

```
my_arr = Array.new(10) { |e| e = e * 2 }
```

produce the following result :

```
[0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18]
```

Though I would expect a : `[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]`.
In my opinion, the element e is not initialzed, so at best its value could be zero (though I would  expect a 'nil'), and zero times some number always return zero. Or I would expect it to be a geometric progression, not an arithmetic progression. So why ???
So there must be something I miss.

And the following code :

```
my_arr = Array.new(10) { |e| e = e + 2 }
```

produce the following result :

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 , 9, 10, 11]
```

Though I would expect a : `[0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18]`.
In my opinion, the element e is not initialzed, so at best its value could be zero (though I would  expect a 'nil'). So it should be an arythmetic progression by 2, not by 1. Why ???

I checked the [ruby reference](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-c-new) and can't find any clue to understand these so unintuitive results.

The idea come from here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_arrays.htm

I think the point relies in explaining what value is the `e` supposed to be representing ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be written as:

```
Array.new(10) { |index| index * 2 } #=> [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
```

Which matches the final form in the documentation to which you linked:

> `new(size) {|index| block }`

Where an array of the given size (10) is created. Each element in this array is created by passing the element’s index to the given block and storing the return value.

The value you assign to `e` in your example is discarded after each element is initialised.

Comment: Yes that's it ! I was mislead that 'e' was an initial current value of the array where it was in fact the index of the current element. The official Ruby doc doesn't explain that the argument passed to the block is the index of the array though. Great thanks !

Comment: @Douglas From the [official docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-c-new) - *In the last form, an array of the given size is created. Each element in this array is created by **passing the element’s index to the given block** and storing the return value.*